# How to create an array of objects and store it in a cookie dynamically

Tags: php, cookies, zend-framework2

I'am trying to create a cookie in ZF2 controller. When I am on a "hotelPage" the controller is supposed to create a cookie with the value of the hotel. I need to add dynamically data to the cookie depending on the hotelPage I am currently on. My code sofar:

```
                $cookieData = $this->getRequest()->getCookie();
            if(empty($cookieData->recently_viewed)){ // cookie doesn't exists                   
                // get data from hotel object
                $recentlyViewedHotel = array('hotelId' => $hotel->id, 'hotelName' => $hotel->name);
                array_push($hotels, $recentlyViewedHotel);
                System::setCookie("recently_viewed", json_encode($hotels) );
            } else{ // cookie already created, add more values to the cookie
                $recentlyViewedHotel = array('hotelId' => $hotel->id, 'hotelName' => $hotel->name);
                System::setCookie("recently_viewed", json_encode($hotels) );
            }
```

The output that I get is an array of one object that is always overwritten. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code and on the basis of what you're getting as output, I think the problem is with the `System::setCookie` function which you're using to set the cookie WHEN your cookie already exists. Try getting the contents of the cookie if the cookie already exists, `json_decode` it. Append the new values into your object and then call the `System::setCookie` function with the updated object.

Note: Obviously, you would need to do the above process, if there isn't any existing API which you can call to append the values to your existing cookie :)

Cheers!